# Checking with if and else if there is a value in sharedpreference

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

I'm trying to check if there is a value in the shared preference, if not, an Alert Dialog with an EditText will be displayed to add the value.

More so far so good, and displayed and the value is inserted and saved.

More when the application is closed and opened again, it displays the dialog asking again for the value that is no longer assigned to Shared Preference

This is my code:

```
public void checkValue() {
SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences("USERCODE", 0);
        if (sp.getString("tag", "") != null)
        {
            openAlert();
        }
        else
        {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Existing value.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

}


private void openAlert()
    {
        mValue = getSharedPreferences("PREFERENCE", MODE_PRIVATE).getBoolean("mValue", true);

        if (mValue)
        {
            AlertDialog.Builder mAlertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

            final View customLayout = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.alert_dialog, null);
            final EditText userInput = customLayout.findViewById(R.id.alertdialogEditTextCode);
            mAlertDialog.setView(customLayout);
            mAlertDialog.setCancelable(false);

            mAlertDialog.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton)
                    {
                        String value = userInput.getText().toString();

                        SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences("USERCODE", 0);
                        SharedPreferences.Editor preferencesEditor = sp.edit();
                        preferencesEditor.putString("tag", value);
                        preferencesEditor.commit();
                        updatdCode();
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Código salvo com sucesso!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        dialog.dismiss();

                    }
                });
            mAlertDialog.show();

            getSharedPreferences("PREFERENCE", MODE_PRIVATE).edit().putBoolean("mValue", true).commit();
        }
    }

    private void updatdCode()
    {
        SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences("USERCODE", 0);
        String data = sp.getString("tag", "");
        mTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.game_title);
        mTextView.setText(data);
    }

}
```

How can this be resolved?

The problem was solved, using a String and calling updatdCode (); at the beginning.

````
package com.vanderclin.app;

import android.app.*;
import android.content.*;
import android.os.*;
import android.view.*;
import android.widget.*;
import com.vanderclin.app.*;

public class MainActivity extends Activity 
{

    private boolean mValue;
    private TextView mTextView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        SharedPreferences sp = this.getSharedPreferences("USERCODE", 0);
        String usercode = sp.getString("CODE", "");
        updatdCode();
        if (usercode == "")
        {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "User not registered.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            mValue = getSharedPreferences("PREFERENCE", MODE_PRIVATE).getBoolean("mValue", true);

            if (mValue)
            {
                AlertDialog.Builder mAlertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

                final View customLayout = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.alert_dialog, null);
                final EditText userInput = customLayout.findViewById(R.id.alertdialogEditTextCode);
                mAlertDialog.setView(customLayout);
                mAlertDialog.setCancelable(false);

                mAlertDialog.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton)
                        {
                            String value = userInput.getText().toString();

                            SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences("USERCODE", 0);
                            SharedPreferences.Editor preferencesEditor = sp.edit();
                            preferencesEditor.putString("CODE", value);
                            preferencesEditor.commit();
                            updatdCode();
                            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Code saved successfully!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            dialog.dismiss();

                        }
                    });
                mAlertDialog.show();

                getSharedPreferences("PREFERENCE", MODE_PRIVATE).edit().putBoolean("mValue", true).commit();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Registered user.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }

    private void updatdCode()
    {
        SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences("USERCODE", 0);
        String data = sp.getString("CODE", "");
        mTextView = findViewById(R.id.mainTextView);
        mTextView.setText(data);
    }

}```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the answer of Brian H., I change it a little bit

```
if (sp.getString("tag", "").equals(""))
{
    openAlert();
}
```

The default value is `""`, so you must compare with empty string. If it equals, then that means there is no value in shared preference.

Sorry I can't comment yet.

Comment: Even using an empty value string it remains the same.

Comment: How about using Device File Explorer and go to data/data/yourapp/shared_prefs to check if it works properly and actually writes into the file. Remember to synchronize each time you perform an action with shared_prefs!

Comment: Doing several tests, I managed to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

> sp.getString("tag", "")

The result of this can never be null, cause if can't find in `SharePreference` it will return the default value which is `""` that you just declare as the second argument.

So you must change to

```
if (!sp.getString("tag", "").equals(""))
```

Comment: I just did the test, but the problem continues.

Comment: Doing several tests, I managed to solve the problem.